# are context managers strictly for generators?

Tags: python, contextmanager

Python's `with exp() as obj:` syntax is appealing for any object which has 'mandatory' enter and exit methods - considering cases where people try extending `obj.__del__` with poor results and all that, it would seem to point one towards the use of `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods instead.

The first thing I thought of was a state machine with enter and exit methods; something that's elementary to handle anyway but makes the actual implementation of the state machine very simple.

```
class State(object):
    def __init__(self, strategy):
        self.strategy = strategy

    def __enter__(self, *args):
        return self

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.strategy(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        clean_up_things()

...
...
...
def state_handle():
    states = (State(foo), State(bar), State(eggs))
    for state in states:
        with state() as s:
            what_ever(s)
```

However it seems that one typically sees `with XXX as YYY` syntax as a replacement for `try/finally` clauses and/or `yield` statements, and one thing I keep finding is that the Python community likes to know what to expect when a certain feature is implemented. So if the wrong spell is used to solve the right problem, it's still the wrong answer.

*Does Python purposely reserve `with...as` syntax for generators for a particular reason, or can one apply this syntax as one sees fit?* If there is a purpose, what is that purpose? (I saw little-to-no mention of `with/as` in PEP 8, if that's even the right place to look)

Comment: The appropriate PEP is [343](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/).

Comment: *However it seems that one typically sees with XXX as YYY syntax as a replacement for try/finally clauses and/or yield statements*. No, one does not.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have misunderstood something.

> [I]t seems that one typically sees with XXX as YYY syntax as a replacement for try/finally clauses and/or yield statements

No, one does not. Context managers can be used *whenever you need to manage a context*. Your use case is just fine.

Using a context manager to replace `try`.. `finally` use is *one* usecase. I am not sure where you got the idea about generators from; perhaps because the helpful [`@contextlib.contextmanager()` decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) lets you turn a generator into a context manager, simplifying creating a context manager.

I can think of at least two counter examples in the Python standard library:

- `unittest`; using [`assertRaises`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) as a context manager lets you assert an exception is raised, then test aspects of the exception.
- `decimal`; [`localcontext`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.localcontext) manages decimal number precision, rounding, and other aspects.

These are not replacements for `try`..`finally` handlers, although you could conceivably get the same functionality for the `decimal` context with `try`..`finally` and an added thread-safety layer; it would be a lot more work, however.

The original Python Enhancement Proposal might be interesting for you to read: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/